# Linking a Date object via :value and @input in a VueJS component

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I have managed to link a date form input with a date object using :value and @input instead of v-model following [this method](https://acdcjunior.github.io/how-bind-date-object-to-input-date-vue.js-v-model.html). It works fine, and allows me to display and change the date in my form input, and to save the updated date in MongoDB. However, my browser console throws an error:

```
vue.runtime.esm.js?2b0e:619 [Vue warn]: Error in render: "TypeError: _vm.item[row.key].split is not a function"

found in

---> <AppForm> at src/components/Utils/Form.vue
       <ItemDetails> at src/components/Item/ItemDetails.vue
         <App> at src/App.vue
           <Root>
```

The setup is the following: a VueJS app is backed up with a NodeJS express server that uses Mongoose to store data. My component ItemDetails (called via router-view) calls the Form component and passes it its 'item' as a prop. The 'item' itself was retrived from the API and is meant to be saved back into it once updated.

When I look at my Form component with DevTools, initally 'item.dueDate' looks like this:

```
2020-06-24T00:00:00.000Z
```

Then when I change the content of the input field, 'item.dueDate' changes to this format:

```
Fri Jun 19 2020 12:00:00 GMT+1200 (New Zealand Standard Time)
```

and this is when I get the error.

However, as soon as I save in database (a simple POST call to the API, followed by function that will re-fetch the clean updated object), item.dueDate is back to the correct format, with the correct updated dueDate. So it all works. I just want to get rid of the console error.

Here is [ItemDetails.vue](https://bpa.st/GRHQ). The 'app-form' call concerned by the issue starts at line 105 ('Task').
Here is [Form.vue](https://bpa.st/XUWQ). The date input starts at line 99.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please include the relevant code in your question

Answer (score 0):

Your data (`item[row.key]`) is alternating between a string and a `Date` instance. `Date` instances do not have a `split()` method, hence your error.

This is due to this piece of code where `value` expects a string (1️⃣) and `@input` changes it to a `Date` (2️⃣)

> 

<input
type="date"
class="form-control form-control-sm bg-dark text-light"
:disabled="user.role < 3"
:value="item[row.key] && item[row.key].split('T')[0]" 1️⃣
@input="item[row.key] = new Date($event.target.valueAsDate)" 2️⃣
/>

> 

You should **not** be modifying the `item` prop value. This violates Vue's [One-Way Data Flow](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#One-Way-Data-Flow) principal. Instead, you should emit the new date (as an [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) string to maintain consistency) to the parent, ie

```html
<input
  type="date"
  ...
  @input="$emit('due-date-update', $event.target.valueAsDate?.toISOString())"
/>
```

and in the parent

```html
<app-form
  :item="item"
  ...
  @due-date-update="item.dueDate = $event"
></app-form>
```